Subscribers inside planner plugin nav2
(ROS2 HUMBLE)
Just a simple question, is it fine to create subscribers or services inside a custom path planner in nav2? the reason I want to do this is because I want to use a set of points to create a plan (the set of points ARE NOT the plan that the robot will follow) but the function createPlan only takes a single goal.
Thank you.

Has anyone ever done it?
